# Submit form using a tag and make onsubmit work

Tags: javascript, html

hello i want to know how to submit form using a tag i know it is

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();"></a>
```

but when i try javascript validation on form eg

```
 <form method="post" onsubmit="valid() name="myform" action="index.php">
```

then the valid function doesn't work so is there any way to make the function work.
I want only a tag to be used as onsubmit.

i used simple alert function for checking the validation but it doesnot worked but when i checked it using input type submit tag then it started working.

Comment: Please show us the code for `valid()`

Comment: function valid()
{
 alert(1); 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onclick()` function is looking for a form with the ID `myform`. In your example code, your form doesn't have an ID or name.

This code should work:

`<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();"></a>`

So long as you include the ID in the form element:

`<form method="post" onsubmit="valid()" name="myform" id="myform">`

Comment: no i have place he name but i know it is working when i use action="index.php" on form tag then it redirect me to it using a tag but when i use onsubmit function of alert on form tag then no alert box come but after i use it by using simple input type submit tag then alert box come

Comment: It won't work, because one quotation mark of onclick attribute is missing.

Comment: So your `<form>` tag does have both `name="myform"` and especially `id="myform"` in the actual code?

Comment: @ghost good catch! OP you ought to see if the closing `"` makes the difference

Comment: i am saying everything is working but only onsumbit is not working while it is working with <input type="submit"/> tag

Answer (score 0):

Historically, form submission via `submit()` JavaScript method does not invoke `submit` event handler (most likely to prevent infinite recursion).

If you want to call a code that is contained inside `onsubmit` attribute, you should call it explicitly before submitting form programmatically. For example:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    link = document.querySelector('a');

link.onclick = function() {
    alert('Handler attached with JS.');
    form.onsubmit.call(form);
    form.submit();
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - `submit()` method does **not** trigger `onsubmit` event. If you want to validate your code *on submit* then you have to call `valid()` function by yourself.

Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit();"></a>
```

which will trigger your `onsubmit` (so it will call `valid()`)

or just:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="valid()"></a>
```

`submit()` method can be then called from that function after positive validation or whenever you want.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit();"></a> worked but then action="index.php" is not called

Comment: i want both to perform i.e action also and onsubmit also is there any way

Comment: oh yes everything is solved it worked with using 2 commands on href tag

    onclick="document.getElementById('registerform').onsubmit();document.getElementById('registerform').submit();"

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is really old. But if someone actually needs a solution 
i.e. in case when one wants required fields to be validated by the browser.

Inside of the form create an

`<input type="submit" name="submit" />`

And the click on the link should actually trigger the click on that submit input:

`<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit.click();"></a>`